# Socket is not receiving data from localhost

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I have c# code which is connecting to localhost ip address 127.0.0.1 and port no. 5939. Connection is happening perfectly but it is not receiving any data. I want it to receive data and save it to text file on my local machine.

Does it not receiving data because it is on the localhost and on the same machine or there is error in my code ..

Here is my code..

```
         byte[] data = new byte[1024];
         string input, stringData;
         String ip = "127.0.0.1";
         Int32 port = 5939;
         string path = "D://ipdata.text";

            if (File.Exists("D://ipsettings.txt"))
            {
                File.Delete("D://ipsettings.txt");
            }


            IPAddress ipad = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipad, port);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipend);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            try
            {
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                while (true)
                {

                    input = "Client here";
                    sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
                    data = new byte[1024];
                    recv = sock.Receive(data);
                    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

                    string df = "";
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
```

My program is not executing after this line..

```
int recv = sock.Receive(data);
```

Please help me to get out of this situation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your server sends data as soon as a connection is initiated (as from your code) or it requires some commands to be sent to it?

Comment: also add timeout to the socket so it won't wait indefinitely.

Comment: @bansi i dont know sir because this is localhost of my own machine..

Comment: The receive is a block call and will wait for data. You can use Socket.BeginReceive or ReceiveAsync which is async. As Bansi also mentioned, how are you sending data to this end point for testing?

Comment: by `server` I mean the application which you are connecting to.

Comment: from the looks of it, may be you don't need the receive outside the `While` loop

Comment: Hi @Adi can you please tell me, whether IP address and port number which you mentioned in your code are of Sender (Client) or Receiver (Server) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the data until unless the Receive function gives you.

use `while` loop to determine whether `data` is available or not.

```
        int recv=0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        while ((recv=sock.Receive(data)) > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
        }
```

Comment: sir i have done this in my code ..please see my updated post.

Comment: @Adi: you are using while loop after reading data. but you need to use while to determine untill unless data is available.check my answer and letme know.